# Passport.js TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Every time I try to log in it returns `Cannot set property 'user' of undefined`, I tried renewing the secrets in .env and updating passport to the latest version. i have followed the documentation to meet the parameters. In the log I can see it gather the user information but it fails on callback.

I've also tried downgrading passport to 0.2.2 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187787/passport-js-github-strategy-callback-always-returns-typeerror-cannot-set-prope), but without results.

**App.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const _ = require("lodash");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport'),
      GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy,
      TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy,
      FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session)

const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

// ----------- Mongo 

const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

const connectionParams = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}

mongoose.connect(url,connectionParams)
    .then( () => {
        console.log('Connected to database ')
    })
    .catch( (err) => {
        console.error(`Error connecting to the database. \n${err}`);
    })

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: 'auto',
    maxAge: 86400000
  },
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 86400000
  })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  googleId: String,
  profileImage: String,
  myCollection: {
    type: Object,
    default: Object
  },
  games: {
    type: Object,
    default: Object
  },
  homebrews: {
    type: Object,
    default: Object
  }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// ----------- Google

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "https://necronomicon.app/auth/google/callback",
        userProfileUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
        passReqToCallback: true
      },
      function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
        User.findOrCreate({
            googleId: profile.id,
            username: profile.displayName,
            profileImage: profile.photos[0].value
          },
          function(err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
          });
      }
    ));

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ["profile"],
  prompt: "select_account"
    }));
    
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: "/"
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log("Successful authentication, redirect home.");
    res.redirect("/");
  });
```

**package.json dependencies**

```
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "blob": "^0.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "canvas-toBlob": "^1.0.0",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html-to-image": "^1.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "memorystore": "^1.6.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.0",
    "mongoose-encryption": "^2.0.2",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "node-boolify": "^1.0.6",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.2.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1",
    "passport-twitter": "^0.1.5",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.5"
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:45:35
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at pass (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:274:43)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at serialized (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:283:7)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/app.js:174:3
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at pass (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:291:9)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at Authenticator.serializeUser (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:296:5)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:43:29)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at Strategy.strategy.success (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:256:13)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at verified (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:189:20)
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/app.js:166:16
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose-findorcreate/index.js:66:11
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5074:18
Aug 26 04:23:07 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Comment: What's happening on line 174 of app.js?

Comment: @robertklep `passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user.id);});` It's the line with `done(null, user.id);`